# Format a cell based on its value relative to that of another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditionally format an Excel spread sheet. I have two columns J and K with 5 rows 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15. I want to make it so that if K10 is greater than J10 it turns green, if K11 is greater than J11 it turns green etc.

so in effect:if Kn > Jn for values of n between 10 and 15

What is the syntax in Excel to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please select J10:K15 starting with J10 then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=K10>J10
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green, OK, OK.

Comment: Note for @help: when you are typing a conditional formatting formula, you refer to the cells based on the relative position from the top-left corner of the area you are selecting to format. ie: if you select block A5:D10, you arrange it so that your desired input results in "TRUE" for A5. ie: '=A5=A4' will be TRUE for A5 if it is the same value as A4, and because there are no '$', this is a relative reference, so when any cell in that block is the same as the one above it, it will be TRUE for that cell also.